# pass parameter to rjs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would be grateful if somebody could help me out with the following problem.

I have the following form:

**new_book form**

```
<% remote_form_for @book, :url => { :controller => "books", :action => "create_sub_book"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :book_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :book_publication %>

    <%= params[:id] %> <!-- I need to pass this value to create_sub_book action, which will then pass it to create_sub_book.js.rjs -->

    <p><%= f.submit 'Create'%></p>

<% end %>
```

**controller action **

```
def create_sub_book

@book = book.new(params[:book])

respond_to do |format|
  if @book.save
    format.js
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Book failed to save."
  end
end
end
```

**create_sub_book.js.rjs **

```
`page.alert(params[:id]) ## On this page I need to access the params[:id] on the 'new_book' form. This line does not work`.
```

Any suggestion on how to pass the params[:id] on the 'new_book' form to the 'create_sub_book.js.rjs' ??

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) tag for this.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id, params[:id] %>
```

This will get inserted in to your params hash, and then you can pass it along.